# Python: Tkinter + SQLITE. Salvar registros no banco de dados e limpar campo

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

estou estudando, por conta própria SQlite, já comprei alguns cursos, porém preciso de uma ajuda.

**Objetivo: Eu gostaria de salvar os campos digitados pelo usuário no banco de dados e, em seguida, limpar os mesmos campos para permitir novas entradas de dados.**

O programa é uma janela com um campo chamado **email** e outro campo chamado **senha** e um botão salvar.

Quando clica no botão salvar, deverá ser salvo no banco de dados três colunas (id auto-incremento, email, senha)

**O código abaixo mostra só o código da janela,**
Mais abaixo, terá o código do módulo usuarios, onde coloco o código SQLite.

```
from tkinter import *
import usuarios


janela = Tk()
janela.title("Cadastro de usuário")
janela["bg"] = "lightblue"
janela.geometry('300x200+700+400')

rotulo = Label(janela,
               font="Arial 18 bold",
               text='Cadastro de usuário',
               bg="lightblue")
rotulo.place(x=25, y=10)

rotulo = Label(janela,
               font="Arial 10",
               text='E-mail:',
               bg="lightblue")
rotulo.place(x=25, y=70)

cxtexto1 = Entry(janela,
                 width=20,
                 font="Arial 12 bold")
cxtexto1.place(x=75, y=70)
email = cxtexto1.get()

rotulo = Label(janela,
               font="Arial 10",
               text='Senha:',
               bg="lightblue")
rotulo.place(x=25, y=100)

cxtexto2 = Entry(janela,
                 width=20,
                 font="Arial 12 bold")
cxtexto2.place(x=75, y=100)
senha = cxtexto2.get()

bt2 = Button(janela,
             width=10,
             text="Salvar",
             font="Arial 12 bold",
             command=usuarios.cria_bd)
bt2.place(x=150, y=130)


janela.mainloop()
```

**O código abaixo mostra o comando para salvar dentro do Sqlite**

```
import sqlite3

def cria_bd(email, senha):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('usuarios.db')
    bd = conn.cursor()
    bd.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cadastro (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        Email TEXT NOT NULL,
        Senha TEXT NOT NULL);""")

    bd.execute("""
    INSERT INTO Cadastro (Email, Senha)
    VALUES (?,?)
    """, (email, senha))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar um método para realizar essas operações:

```
def salvar():
    email = cxtexto1.get()
    senha = cxtexto2.get()
    usuarios.cria_bd(email, senha)
    cxtexto1.delete(0, END)
    cxtexto2.delete(0, END)
```

Utilizando o seu código de **exemplo** temos:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""""""
from tkinter import *
import usuarios


def salvar():
    email = cxtexto1.get()
    senha = cxtexto2.get()
    usuarios.cria_bd(email, senha)
    cxtexto1.delete(0, END)
    cxtexto2.delete(0, END)


janela = Tk()
janela.title("Cadastro de usuário")
janela["bg"] = "lightblue"
janela.geometry('300x200+700+400')

rotulo = Label(janela, font="Arial 18 bold", text='Cadastro de usuário', bg="lightblue")
rotulo.place(x=25, y=10)

rotulo = Label(janela, font="Arial 10", text='E-mail:', bg="lightblue")
rotulo.place(x=25, y=70)

cxtexto1 = Entry(janela, width=20, font="Arial 12 bold")
cxtexto1.place(x=75, y=70)

rotulo = Label(janela, font="Arial 10", text='Senha:', bg="lightblue")
rotulo.place(x=25, y=100)

cxtexto2 = Entry(janela, width=20, font="Arial 12 bold")
cxtexto2.place(x=75, y=100)

bt2 = Button(janela, width=10, text="Salvar", font="Arial 12 bold", command=salvar)
bt2.place(x=150, y=130)

janela.mainloop()
```

No banco (`usuarios.py`) você não precisa do `return` no final, visto que nada está sendo retornado:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""""""
import sqlite3


def cria_bd(email, senha):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('usuarios.db')
    bd = conn.cursor()
    bd.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cadastro (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        Email TEXT NOT NULL,
        Senha TEXT NOT NULL);""")

    bd.execute("""INSERT INTO Cadastro (Email, Senha) VALUES (?,?);""", (email, senha))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Cuido apenas com o `conn.close()` no final do método, isso porque se você for realizar mais operações com o banco a conexão estará fechada.

Comment: Caro  @Renato Cruz, agradeço sua atenção! Muito obrigado!